# Visual Studio Code Randomly Started Unfolding All on Save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have no idea why this has happened though out of the blue, with no real reason Visual Studio Code 1.48.2 will now unfold all code every time the file is saved.

It is incredibly annoying and was wondering if there is any way to rectify this? I have uninstalled and reinstalled. Removed all extensions and tried toggling varying things in settings and nothing has worked.

If anyone does know how to correct this is would be great.

Comment: One idea: Do you have "format on save" checked in settings?  If so, uncheck it and see if the problem still happens.  If it fixes the problem, the issue is something related to your foramtter.

Comment: Thanks however that is not checked so can't be the problem.

Comment: I have submitted the issue on GitHub under Visual Studio Code bugs and was informed that the issue could be as a result of the Go Extension for VS Code. The issue has been posted on the GitHub Go Extension bugs page. Will update once feedback has been received

Answer (score 1):

Finally found something that seems to work (for me)

- Open SETTINGS
- Search for FORMAT ON SAVE
- Turn FORMAT ON SAVE on (ticked)
- Change FORMAT ON SAVE MODE to *modifications*